# Animating the text in a UILabel if text content is greater than the label size

Tags: ios5

I have a text which is greater then UILabel size. How can I animate the label text horizontally (ticker tape animation) when the label text exceeds the width of the label?

I have not any clue how to do this .

Thanks,
Plz help

Comment: Please provide more information. Do you want to animate the text? Or change its position?

Comment: @jstr I want to animate text horizontally.